# Why have they cut scenes showing T-1000 malfunctions?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series

Why have they cut scenes showing T-1000 malfunctions? Except the last one when John  recognize that T-1000 morphed into Sarah?

Comment: Why do you cut anything from a movie ever? To make it shorter, to take away things which are not essential to the plot, make the story more compact.

Comment: Is the question "why were those scenes cut?" or is it "why were those scenes shot in the first place?"

Comment: Maybe they thought it made the T-1000 less menacing if it was shown beginning to malfunction?

Comment: If they wanted to make the film shorter, they could have cut quite a number of _T1000 gets shot; sustains "wounds"; the "wounds" slowly shrink and disappear"_ scenes. Those got old after a while.

Comment: @TLP look at answer Kely Jones posted, it's great, in the topic such deeply digged as Terminator 2 such questions really have sense, there are so many materials because of the status of the film

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the *Terminator 2* Ultimate Edition DVD there is a featurette called ["More Than Meets The Eye"](http://videosift.com/video/Terminator-2-Deleted-Scenes-and-Why-They-Were-Cut) in which director James Cameron explains why the T-1000 glitch scenes were created and why they were absent from the theatrical version of the film:

> "The glitching was meant to give some tiny ray of hope that it was possible to destroy this thing, it was possible to affect it in some way.  They freeze it, they shatter it, and it reforms and comes after them again, but he's not working quite as well as he used to.  I went for the linear thrust and took it out as a kind of embellishment that we didn't really need at that point."